# Is there a way to add two complex vectors and get both magnitude and phase?

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, vector-analysis

Let us consider a spherical coordinate system and an electric field that has two complex components, $E_\theta$ and $E_\phi$. There is no dependence with $r$. Therefore, at any pair of coordinates $(\theta,\phi)$ you have two components $E_\theta(\theta,\phi)\hat{\theta}$ and $E_\phi(\theta,\phi)\hat{\phi}$. My basic knowledge tells me that with conventional methods I can only find the magnitude of the addition of the two by calculating as $|E_{total}(\theta,\phi)|=\sqrt{|E_\theta(\theta,\phi)|^2 + |E_\phi(\theta,\phi)|^2}$. However there is no clue or way to calculate the phase. Is there some mathematical technique to do that? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Your title mentions complex vectors, and then your question has no mention of complex vectors, so it's hard to understand what you are asking.

Comment: I think you did not read the text. If not obvious though, $\hat{\theta}$ is the unitary vector of the coordinate system. Practically you have 2 complex vector functions that have different values at any pair of $(\theta,\phi)$. You want to add them and get the phase as well. Is there a way?

Comment: I still don't understand. What I get from this is that $\hat\theta$ and $\hat\phi$ are the unit vector fields of the spherical coordinate system on $S^2 - \{N,S\}$, where $N,S$ are the north and south poles of the sphere $S^2$. And so, at first, $\hat\theta$ and $\hat\phi$ are vector fields on the 2-dimensional real tangent bundle of $S^2 - \{N,S\}$. Now you want to complexify that tangent bundle, i.e. takes its tensor product with the complex numbers $\mathbb C$? And then study complex linear combinations of $\hat\theta$ and $\hat\phi$ in the complexified bundle?

Comment: Think a given point in the sphere coordinate system, i.e., at $(\theta_1,\phi_1)$. At this point 2 complex vectors exist, $E_\theta(\theta_1,\phi_1)\hat{\theta}$ and $E_\phi(\theta_1,\phi_1)\hat{\phi}$. The $E_\theta(\theta_1,\phi_1)$ is just a complex number or a phasor, whatever form you like. Same for $E_\phi(\theta_1,\phi_1)$. Obviously the vectors are perpendicular and thus, you can find the magnitude of their addition as the square root of their norms. What I am asking is, can you find the phase of the vector of the addition? Is there any way?

Comment: My question started from the fact that when we calculate radiation patterns in antenna theory and have multiple e-field components we only work with the magnitude of their addition. This made me wonder if there is an analytical solution to find the phase of the total electric field and not only the magnitude. I know it is something very complex that's why I asked the math community if there is a way to find the phase of such a vector. I am an engineer, thus, forgive me if my math notation or wording is not /appropriate for/on par with/ mathematicians level of math understanding.

Comment: The conventions of mathematicians and physicists can indeed be quite different. If there is a good answer to your question, it is probably rooted in the conventions of physicists. The only way I can think of expressing your question mathematically is what I wrote in my previous comment --- complex vectors don't just exist, they are elements of complex vector spaces, and so I was trying to figure out just what complex vector space to consider (or even better, what complex vector bundle). But anyway, that does not lead me to any kind of answer to your question about phase.

Comment: Perhaps https://physics.stackexchange.com might be a more fruitful place for your question.